# Does a multi-level hostname makes a practical difference?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

The `A` record for `hello.world.example.com` can be registered

- as the `hello` entry in the domain `world.example.com`
- or as the `hello.world` entry in the domain `example.com`

Is there a practical difference, **from the perspective of the services which resolve the name**, between these two approaches?

As far as I can tell, the resolution of both of them yields the value A record (the IP) so the replies are not discernable for the client.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There will be potentially be an extra delay as creating a separate zone for the `world.example.com` subdomain typically also implies delegation to different authoritative name servers.

If the same authoritative nameservers are used for both the `example.com` and the `world.example.com` zones there is no performance difference.

---

DNS resolvers need to follow the delegation from the TLD to an authoritative name server.

When the resolver reaches authoritative name servers for the `example.com` domain and you have a resource record for `hello.world(.example.com.)` in that zone a response will sent immediately.

If the authoritative name servers for the `example.com` domain are also authoritative for the `world.example.com` sub-domain, the response for the `hello.world.example.com.` record will also be sent immediately.

If `world.example.com` is configured as separate a zone the authoritative name servers for the `example.com` will send a response with further delegation details and the `NS` record(s) of authoritative name servers for the `world.example.com.` zone:

```
world.example.com.  IN NS ns.world.example.com.
world.example.com.  IN NS ns1.example.org.
; GLUE
ns.world.example.com. IN A 192.2.0.1
```

The resolver will need to follow that delegation and sent extra queries to:

1. potentially locate those name servers (for example in the case of the ns1.example.org. NS record)
2. query one of the authoritative name servers for the `world.example.com.` zone for the `hello(.world.example.com.)` record.

Comment: Thank you. So this is rather a matter of performance in the resolution (or speed / easiness of setup) more than technical differences in the response (for a client requesting a resolution, it will not make a difference, it will get an IP for `hello.world.example.com`), correct?

Comment: Yes, either way the resolver should get a response with an ip-address for hello.world.example.com.

Comment: @WoJ, it's usually more a matter of administration — you'd delegate the zone if it is easier to maintain this way. The performance difference is usually negligible.

Answer (score 8):

Technically, as I understand DNS, only the `hello` part is considered the host name, the rest is the domain name. As such, it resolves the same way, in your case the DNS zone includes both the `example.com` and the subdomain `world.example.com`, it's just a matter of preference how you annotate it.

However, the only time I've ever seen records like that are for DKIM and other TXT records, for example DKIM uses `[selector]._domainkey`as the record for a given subdomain or the root domain. Handy of course if you only need a couple of records for a subdomain, no need to create a separate zone for them.

Comment: I know that it is possible to differentiate between them (by querying the `SOA` for instance) and this is why I added the "practical" aspect of the differentiation. Your examples for DKIM are good ones of a real-life case of such entries.