# Does creating a 10th level domain require creating 9 domain that preced to it?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, dns-hosting

Let's say, I own a domain `example.com` and it's setup correctly in my domain management dashboard. Now I want to create a long subdomain of the 10th level:

`d10.d9.d8....d2.example.com`

Will all that require that I somehow specify the IP addresses, or whatever what's required, for **all the 9 domains** that preced it? Or can I go straight to `d10.` and specify the IP address **for `d10` only**?

Comment: you can `c.r.e.a.t.e.s.u.b.dom.tld in a 1.2.3.4` and don't need any other than that

Answer (score 1):

A major misconception is that a dot in a name is necessarily a delegation. It is NOT.

Said otherwise, in the zonefile of `example.com` you can totally have this line:

```
d10.d9.d8.d7.d6.d5.d4.d3.d2.d1.d0 300 IN TXT "why not?"
d10.d9.d8.d7.d6.d5.d4.d3.d2.d1.d0 300 IN A 192.0.2.42
```

You can look at my longer answer for a similar question ("Do intermediate subdomains need to exist?") at https://serverfault.com/a/973788/396475
from which I am copying here only this:

> TL;DR: yes intermediate subdomains need to exist, at least when queried for, per definition of the DNS; they may not exist in the zonefile though.

Comment: And this capability is heavily relied upon in reverse IPv6 zones (they wouldn't literally work without it).

Comment: @Tomek Yes, this is one typical use case, described in my longer answer linked to from there, I did also add other typical cases of such "long" names.