# Wildcard DNS entry is broken by more specific (but non-matching) DNS entry

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I have the following DNS entries for the root domain `example.com`:

- `*` CNAME record pointing to `foo.com`
- `dummy.api` TXT record containing the value `dummy`

When I try to resolve `bla.foo.com` then it correctly resolves to the CNAME entry, but when I try to resolve `api.foo.com`, the DNS server fails to resolve. This would make sense to me if there was a TXT entry for `api.foo.com`, but in this case there is only a TXT entry for the more specific domain `dummy.api.foo.com`.

Is it expected that a more specific domain overrides a wildcard match even if it's only a partial match, like in this case? And is there any way to fix this other than adding an explicit CNAME record for `api`?

For context: this is happening on Azure DNS and specifically _acme-challenge TXT records that are being created for Let's Encrypt.

Comment: There are no "partial" match in DNS. The node is either there, or not, or implied by downstreams (called Empty Non-Terminals, on that maybe look at my answer here for deeper explanation: https://serverfault.com/a/973788/396475). And CNAME + wildcards have all sorts of edge cases, some being as designed (but still unexpected/hard to understand, I think this is the case you list), or not.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this situation is covered by section 2.2.2 in RFC 4592 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4592), which states that the record `dummy.api.example.com` results in the implicit existence of an empty record `api.example.com`, which is why the wildcard entry stops matching. Therefore the only solution is to add an explicit entry for `api.example.com` with the same CNAME as the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

When was the DNS record created/amended?
Try checking the entry on something like:
https://www.whatsmydns.net/

How are you trying to resolve the DNS entry?

If you are using a linux terminal try something like the following:

```
dig a api.foo.com +trace
```

This will give you a full output through all the DNS resolvers that your request travels and will show you the final reply from the Authoritive Name Server which should rule out any caching issues.